# Colate custom field information from bugs and PBIs

Tags: azure-devops

We've added and enforced a "Summary" field to our PBIs and bugs in Azure DevOps, this is so work performed can be described in non-technical terms. We'd like a simple way to collect the summary field from DevOps for a specific branch. Is something like this possible?

I tried creating a view within Azure DevOps but was unable to select the "Summary" field. Therefore when viewing the data through Power BI desktop I could not see the information we're trying to retrieve.

Comment: What's the data type of "Summary field"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add fields with a data type of Plain Text (long text) or HTML (rich-text). These fields aren't available from Analytics for the purposes of reporting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-views-create?view=azure-devops#3-select-the-fields-to-appear-in-the-report

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want  the custom summary field in the bug work item to be displayed in the PBI.

To do this ,you can create a custom Analytics view to define the filtered set of data, and then load the view using the [Power BI Data Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops).

You can select the custom field to appear in the report in the Fields tab of New View dialog.

[image]

For details guide , please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-views-create?view=azure-devops).